# How to keep React Native running like media players (could be "foreground")?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

How can I keep a React Native app running, even if it's in the "foreground"? What I mean by this is something like media player apps do (Spotify, Netflix, etc) that usually display a sticky notification.
I need the app to keep listening to external events (not necessarily a server) and also to continually do things from time to time.
In other words, I don't want the OS to kill the app and I don't mind letting the user know of this (even better if the user knows).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AppState` of `React-native`

`AppState` can tell you if the app is in the foreground or background, and notify you when the state changes.

`AppState` is frequently used to determine the intent and proper behavior when handling push notifications.

**Usage**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native';

class AppStateExample extends Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === 'active'
    ) {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  };

  render() {
    return <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting then that I do something if I detect that the app changes the state, in order to prevent it closing it?
As far as know that AppState won't detect if my app is being closed in order to prevent it (which is my main concern). I don't mind it being on the background since some things are still running.

Comment: ou can't stop he from shutting down the app. For Android, however, it can have a similar effect to Netflix through the listener of the Android navigation button.

Comment: And it can cause changes in screen size through Appstate.